# Check whether two variables are related

Tags: regression, correlation, linear-model

I need urgent help with understanding some (supposedly) simple stats.

I have conducted a survey where experts rank crops based on their attractiveness to pollinators. I want to check whether the number of responses/species is influenced by the position of the species in one of the four separate lists. Eyeballing the data shows that species on list 1 have been scored more than the ones on species 2, 3, and especially 4.

How in the world do I check this in Excel or R? Please explain it in layman terms, as my brain would rather implode than grasp stats (my teacher expects me to do this analysis in my sleep).

---

[image]

I hope this helps. My species are separated into 4 lists (List No. 1–4), and the sample size is the number of observations/ratings for each species. I want to check whether the list (a species being on one of the lists) has an influence on the number of observations.

The simple average values for each list show that clearly, with species on List 1 having more observations than those on List 2, and those on List 2 have more than those on List 3, and finally, List 3 has more observations than List 4 on average.

But I want to know whether: the number of observations can be predicted based on the position on the lists. For example: If I put a new species on List 3, what is the probable no. of observations I could get?

Please excuse my layman speech, but this is the best I can do. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What methods do you know for assessing if two variables are related?

Comment: I don't know any. But I am supposed to know some. Hence my stress. I read about regression models online, for example, but fail to apply them to my data. I have one variable which is categorical (List 1, 2, 3, and 4), and another which is numerical. I want to see if a species is likely to be rated more depending on which list it is on.

Comment: I think you want something like one-way ANOVA or Kruskal-Wallis test followed by an appropriate post-hoc test. Maybe read about those, they will tell you whether there is a significant difference between the scores of **at least** two lists (the post-hoc tests tell you **which** lists differ). But they are based on certain assumptions etc, I think there are good explanations out there. I suppose the lists are groups/factors -> regression doesn't make much sense in this case. You want to compare groups, it seems.